# Can I include link to a third-party app store in Google Play app description?

Tags: android

I have an app released on both Samsung App store and Google Play. Can I add link to Samsung App inside my apps's description on Google Play? Does this violate any Google policy?

Comment: dont think so...should not be a problem...hv seen apps linkin to developers homepage .besides whats the point(jst of curiosity) ?